# Replace values based on column to built cluster

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, cluster-computing

Is it possible to replace values in many columns.
My goal is to replace all values based on the columns to create something like a cluster.

There is a matrix looking like this with like 1000 columns

|  | Blue | Red | Orange | Green | Cyan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 0.0 | nan | nan | nan | 0.8 |
| Red | nan | 0.0 | nan | nan | nan |
| Orange | nan | nan | 0.0 | nan | nan |
| Green | nan | nan | nan | 0.0 | nan |
| Cyan | 0.8 | nan | nan | nan | 0.0 |

It should look like this at the end:

|  | Blue | Red | Orange | Green | Cyan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blue | 1 | nan | nan | nan | 5 |
| Red | nan | 2 | nan | nan | nan |
| Orange | nan | nan | 3 | nan | nan |
| Green | nan | nan | nan | 4 | nan |
| Cyan | 1 | nan | nan | nan | 5 |

In best case the cluster with same values like 1 and 5 should be assigned as one Cluster.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to fill in the required cells, then the solution is as follows:

First, data is read from the file from the column names, another column is created, which is converted into indexes.
Two arrays are created for indexing by indices and columns (the result is placed in a tuple, because without it a warning is issued, but the code works without it):

```
hist = len(df)
tuple([np.arange(hist)] * 2)
```

The array is formed from 1 to the length of the data frame, this array fills the data diagonally based on indices:

```
np.arange(1, hist + 1)
```

Well, then the rest of the data is filled in through iloc, where the indexes are in square brackets on the left, and the column numbers are on the right.
All together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header=0)

df['index'] = df.columns
df = df.set_index('index')

hist = len(df)
df.values[tuple([np.arange(hist)] * 2)] = np.arange(1, hist + 1)
df.iloc[[0, -1], 0] = 1.0
df.iloc[[0], -1] = float(hist)
print(df)
```

Output

```
        Blue  Red  Orange  Green  Cyan
index                                 
Blue     1.0  NaN     NaN    NaN   5.0
Red      NaN  2.0     NaN    NaN   NaN
Orange   NaN  NaN     3.0    NaN   NaN
Green    NaN  NaN     NaN    4.0   NaN
Cyan     1.0  NaN     NaN    NaN   5.0
```